# Change color of itemize bullet

Tags: itemize, enumitem, bullets

In the code below, I wanted to change the default color of the itemize bullet from black to blue with a shadow.  Can you help me accomplish this?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={$\blacktriangleright$}]
\item First item in the list
\item Second item
\item and so on
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution using no new packages, only `xcolor`.

You can add shadow to any symbol or text using the command created here, `\ourshadow`.

[image]**Output**

**Code**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength{\tmpShadow}
\newcommand{\ourShadow}[2]{%
    \settowidth{\tmpShadow}{#1}
    \addtolength{\tmpShadow}{.1em}
    \raisebox{-0.25ex}{\textcolor{gray!70}{#1}}%
    \kern-\tmpShadow%
    \textcolor{#2}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={\ourShadow{$\blacktriangleright$}{blue!80}}]
\item First item in the list
\item Second item
\item and so on
\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are two options using `tikz`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand*{\MyShadow}{\tikz \draw [baseline, fill=blue,draw=blue,circular drop shadow] circle (2pt);}
\newcommand*{\MyBall}{\tikz \draw [baseline, ball color=red, draw=red] circle (2pt);}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label={\MyShadow}]
\item First item in the list
\item Second item
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[label={\MyBall}]
\item First item in the 
\item Second item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also see answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329990/81156