# How do I change the color of itemize bullet? specific and default

Tags: color, itemize

I want to change the color of the bullet on `itemize`. How to do so?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A per-`\item` change of colour is possible using the optional argument of `\item[..]`, and using the same label as `itemize` - `$\bullet$` or `\textbullet`.

For changing the default settings, you can either supply an updated `label` to the `itemize` environment, or create your own using `\newlist` together with `\setlist`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

A list with a specific \verb|\item| changed:
\begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item[\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}] Second item
  \item Last item
\end{itemize}

Default \verb|itemize| list with updated \verb|label|:
\begin{itemize}[label=\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{itemize}

Completely new list \verb|coloritemize|:
\newlist{coloritemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[coloritemize]{label=\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}}

\begin{coloritemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{coloritemize}

\end{document}
```

You can further customise the output to use a colour of your choice. Here's one such option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\newlist{coloritemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[coloritemize]{label=\textcolor{itemizecolor}{\textbullet}}
\colorlet{itemizecolor}{.}% Default colour for \item in itemizecolor

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\colorlet{itemizecolor}{red}

\begin{coloritemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{coloritemize}

\colorlet{itemizecolor}{blue}

\begin{coloritemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{coloritemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this about MS Word document or which document?

Comment: Its an amazing thing to do, but can we do it in Microsoft word too?

Comment: @paul: Create your list. Select the bullets. Right-click. Choose a colour.

Comment: Would it be possible through `\setlist` to color all labels with a unique color for `itemize`, `enumerate` and `descriptions` env. globally without going through the redefinition of each of them?

Comment: @pluton: See [this attempt](https://pastebin.com/raw/9YDMBPuU).

Comment: Thanks! Shall I ask the question so that you can answer on StackExchange? This is funny that this is not more straigthforward.

Comment: @Werner The issue with your solution is when there are embedded lists (ie enumerate within enumerate for instance): all labels are set to `label=\arabic*.`. Sale comment applies to embedded itemize lists with `\textbullet`. I would like to keep the by  default labels and change the color only, for all of them.

Comment: @pluton: You can define how each of the nested lists would look as well, knowing what the default looks like.

Comment: @Werner I agree but it is fairly long. I was hoping for an easy solution :)

Comment: @pluton: I had a similar interest when using the [`titlesec` package](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) a while back. You can not change only a single element of the sectional construction. Instead you have to specify the entire layout of the sectional unit. Anyway, it escaped me until today. Try using the `font` key to set the colour for `enumerate` and `itemize`. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/J0GUkRbx). It works across nested lists.

Comment: @werner Oh!! Perfect. I did not think about the `\font` key. Maybe I should properly ask the question? I think it could be of interest to other users.

Comment: @pluton: Sure...

Comment: @Werner https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546293/371

Comment: Any chance you know how to do the same in the beamer document class? Unfortunately, the above solutions don't work there

Answer (score 5):

You may also use [the following solution](https://texblog.org/2008/10/16/lists-enumerate-itemize-description-and-how-to-change-them/) (e.g. if you want to change style of your itemised list globally but don't want to renew commands to keep use of its optional parameters):

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\textcolor{blue}{\bullet}$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\textcolor{blue}{\cdot}$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\textcolor{blue}{\diamond}$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\textcolor{blue}{\ast}$}
```