# How to change the color of an enumerate number in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, enumerate

As seen in [How do I change the color of itemize bullet? specific and default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329990/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-itemize-bullet-specific-and-default), it is easy to change the color of an `itemize` item bullet like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item[\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}] Second item
  \item Last item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

How can I do the equivalent for an `enumerate` environment? Is there something like `\textbullet` that gives me the complete label for the current item? (ideally the label itself, formatted as per the `label` environment option, if given, although the I could work with the raw item number otherwise). I have tried `\labelenumi` and `\theenumi` (without understanding very well what these are exactly) and it did not work.

*EDIT:*

The document I am working is a Beamer presentation. I did not mention it initially because I did not think it was relevant to the question, but indeed the nice answers provided by [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425160/56206) and [user94293](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425167/56206), while absolutely correct for article, do not work in my presentation.

Comment: You want tho change the colour of *some* labels of the environment, not all?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, that's right. The use case, if you want context, is having a list of steps where some of them are "done", hence should be in green (both the label and the item text, but I already know how to change the color of the text).

Comment: For beamer, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14319/

Comment: You could do a trick like    `{\color<2>{red!50!white}
\item \mbox{}}   test      \item another item`  inside your `enumerate` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  {
      \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=green}
        \color{green}
      \item Second item
  }
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Or much easier using the alert feature of beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item<alert@+-> Second item
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost right! But to get it to work with `enumerate` I had to replace `itemize item` with `local structure`. Otherwise, it works fine.

Comment: Use `\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=green}` for enumerate lists.

Comment: @samcarter This solution does not seem to work with `\begin{enumerate}[<+->]`

Comment: @user94293 Thanks for pointing this out. I added a second much easier solution which also works in this case.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

You can use `\normalcolor` to switch back to the normal color.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \color{blue}
  \item \normalcolor Third item
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \color{blue}
  \item Third item
  \normalcolor
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Much simpler than my solution!

Comment: Huh, never thought of trying this, thanks! However, this is not working in my case... I'm using Beamer, sorry for not specifying it in the question in the first place, I didn't think it would be relevant... I'll update the question..

Comment: this one, saved me! thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a (comparatively) simple way withe the `resume*`  and `before` keys:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}\color{DarkSeaGreen}]
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}]
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*

Here is a solution for `beamer`, with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
 {\pretocmd{\insertenumlabel}{\color{DarkSeaGreen}}{}{}\color{DarkSeaGreen}
 \item Third item}
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a working solution. I was hoping for something analogous to the `itemize` case, but if no better proposals are posted I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Bernard : Could you explain what does "before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}"?

Comment: @pzorba75 presumably make the vspacing even

Comment: @pzorba75: Exactly as daleif said. With custom \itemsep, \topsep, \partopsep, it might have to be adapted

Comment: Sorry, I've realised that when I go to my actual answer this didn't work either! It's a Beamer document, sorry for not specifying, didn't think it changed the answer....

Comment: Yes, beamer has its own way of managing lists and  enumitem doesn't work in this context.

Comment: @jdehesa: I've added a solution for beamer.

Comment: For a reasonable new beamer version `\usepackage{etoolbox}` is not necessary

Comment: @samcarter: I didn't know beamer loads etoolbox (actually I didn't even think of checking).  I've removed the corresponding line. Thanks!

Comment: @Bernard It was only added a year or so ago