# Custom itemize symbols with dynamic color

Tags: macros, itemize, pifont

I have succeeded in building an itemize environment with circled number symbols that auto-increment thanks to the `pifont` package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}

\begin{dingautolist}{202} % pifont symbol number for solid numbered circles
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{dingautolist}

\end{document}
```

Now I would like to dynamically adjust the color of each itemize symbol. I tried changing the first item as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329990/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-itemize-bullet-specific-and-default)

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\item[\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}] First item
```

However this reverts the item symbol to the standard bullet instead of the symbol used by `dingautolist`. In the post, there is no discussion of using a command other than `\textbullet` as the argument to `\textcolor`.

How can I adjust the color while retaining my custom symbols? Ideally I would create `\newcommand`s like `\blueitem[1]{def}` and `\reditem[1]{def}` which accept a single argument for the text to display with the item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following provides `\colouritem{<colour>}` that works just like `\item`, but sets the colour using `\color{<colour>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont,xcolor}

\newcommand{\colouritem}[1]{%
  {\color{#1}\item\leavevmode}\ignorespaces%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{dingautolist}{202} % pifont symbol number for solid numbered circles
  \item First item
  \colouritem{blue} Second item
  \colouritem{red} Last item
\end{dingautolist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding \label{referb} to the first \colouritem statement and  \label{referc} to the second \colouritem statement doesn't provide the right value when referring in a later \refer{referb} sentence, ils print the first item (1 in a black disk). Is there a way to correct this situation very confusing?

Comment: @pzorba75: One would have to use a completely different approach to capture the colour of the label and transport that with the reference. [Ask a follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)...