# Enumitem: global color modification of (possibly nested) list labels

Tags: color, lists, enumitem

Would it be possible through the `\setlist` of the `enumitem` package to globally color all labels with a unique color for itemize, enumerate and descriptions environments without going through the redefinition of each of them and keeping their default format otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and will trickle down to nested lists if you set the `font` key, since the default font attribute is empty *except* for `description` which has a default of `\bfseries`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\setlist[itemize]{font=\color{itemizecolor}}
\colorlet{itemizecolor}{.}% Default colour for \item in itemize
\setlist[enumerate]{font=\color{enumeratecolor}}
\colorlet{enumeratecolor}{.}% Default colour for \item in enumerate
\setlist[description]{font=\bfseries\color{descriptioncolor}}
\colorlet{descriptioncolor}{.}% Default colour for \item[.] in description

\begin{document}

\colorlet{itemizecolor}{red}
\colorlet{enumeratecolor}{blue}
\colorlet{descriptioncolor}{green}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
  \item[First] item
  \item[Second] item
  \item[Last] item
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\color{red}\arabic*.}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\color{blue}\textbullet}

\begin{document}
\section*{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\section*{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
    \item test
    \item test
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes but you set all nested lists to `textbullet` labels, which I want to avoid. I want to keep the default format of all lists.

Comment: If you just want to change it for the outer environment in a nested situation, just add a 1, like `\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\color{red}\arabic*.}` in the definitions. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes but I want to change the color for all list levels without affecting other list features...

Comment: Ok, then you would need to redefine each level of each list seperately.