# Change color to all items in enumerate: only the "indicator"

Tags: color, enumerate, itemize, code

I don't know the right terminology, but what I am looking for is this: say I write

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\setcounter{enumi}{-1}
\item blabla
\item $x - 3 = 0 \iff x = 3$
\item The End.
\end{enumerate}
```

The output would be like

(1) blabla

(2) $x - 3 = 0 \iff x = 3$

(3) The End

Is there a way to have ONLY the numbers indicators coloured (I call them indicators because if I start nesting the enumerates, they change with letters, then with $i$ and so on...)?

Something like

\color{red}{(1)} blabla

\color{red}{(2)} $x - 3 = 0 \iff x = 3$

\color{red}{(3)} The End

Thank you! (Seems like here colors don't work, but you perhaps understand what I wish for).

**ADD**

I tried to use this code

```
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\color{red}\arabic*.}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\color{blue}\textbullet}

\begin{document}
\section*{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}

\section*{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

From this question: [Enumitem: global color modification of (possibly nested) list labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546293/enumitem-global-color-modification-of-possibly-nested-list-labels)

But it doesn't work.

**ADD 2**

The problems lie in the contrast between

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

With the first one it's all ok, I can use

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
```

and other "styles" (like using [a] or [i]), but this turns into errors if I switch to ENUMITEM.

On the contrary, with ENUMITEM I can have the labels coloured but I cannot have the styles of the labels.

Yet the part

```
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\color{red}\arabic*.}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\color{blue}\textbullet}
```

returns error if I use ENUMERATE.

Comment: Please add a documentclass to your code. Some classes have build in mechanism to colour the itemize item.

Comment: Don't load `enumitem` and `enumerate` simultaneously.

Comment: @Mico Yes that I got myself too. The problem has anyway been solved, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\textcolor{red}{(\arabic*)}}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}}

\begin{document}

\section*{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}

Changing the label with \texttt{enumitem}'s syntax:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{green}{\alph*}]
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}

Changing the label with \texttt{enumerate}'s syntax:
\begin{enumerate}[\color{purple}(a)]
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}

\section*{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Soo, this works, so thank you! But the problems remain if I wish to use, for example,     \begin{enumerate}[a]
it returns an error

Comment: @Henry Yes, this will fail because you're trying to use the syntax from the package `enumerate` with `enumitem`. In general, `enumitem` has the option `shortlabels` to make it accept `enumerate`'s syntax, but unfortunately I don't think it would be possible to use this short syntax while still changing the color. If you want to change the appearance of the counter, you'd have to use `enumitem`'s syntax. I can add another example if that's helpful.

Comment: Some examples with the shotlabels option would be amazing, thank you! And thank you again for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @Henry I added two more examples to show how to change labels: one with `enumitem`'s syntax and one with `enumerate`'s (which is what `enumitem`'s `shortlabels` option is for). And in fact I was mistaken, it does work to change the color with `enumerate`'s syntax.

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you so much!!