# coloring bullets in nested lists

Tags: color, lists, itemize, nesting, bullets

I would like to color bullets in my lists (for example, to signify tasks that are done or not/hard or easy, etc.), including in nested lists.

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329990/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-itemize-bullet-specific-and-default) and successfully used it. Since I would like to color different bullets in the same list in different colors, I used the `\def` function to define a few shortcuts, and it works in the code below, but the way the nested lists turn out is not ideal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\def\itemr{\item[\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}]}
\def\itemg{\item[\textcolor{green}{\textbullet}]}

\begin{document}

\section*{Hey!}

\begin{itemize}
   \item Now we test the colors
   \itemr This one should be in red
   \itemg This one green
   \itemg Only the bullets themselves are colored, which is the goal
   \begin{itemize}
         \item Now notice what happens when I color the nested list bullets too
         \item While the uncolored are dashes
         \itemr The colored ones are level 1 bullets again
         \itemr While I would like them to be colored dashes
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled in Overleaf]

I know why this is so - `\textbullet` refers to the specific type of bullet. I know I can define different shortcuts for different levels. The question is if there is a master code for "the default bullet label in this level, whatever level we're on" that I can use instead of `\textbullet`, so that I don't have to think each time at what level I am (might have four levels of nesting, maybe more).

I would also appreciate any other way to do what I'm asking so long as it does not involve a lot of hassle on the flow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the definitions of the labels that are set at each level within an `itemize`. They have the form `\labelitem<level>`, where `<level>` is a roman numeral (taken from [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co)):

```
\newcommand\labelitemi  {\labelitemfont \textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii {\labelitemfont \bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\labelitemfont \textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{ \labelitemfont \textperiodcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemfont{\normalfont}
```

You can tap into/update `\labelitemfont` to be the colour you're interested in and then just set the item as per usual in the following way:

```
\def\itemr{{\renewcommand{\labelitemfont}{\color{red}}\item\leavevmode\ignorespaces}}
\def\itemg{{\renewcommand{\labelitemfont}{\color{green}}\item\leavevmode\ignorespaces}}
```

Or, even easier:

```
\def\itemr{{\color{red}\item\leavevmode\ignorespaces}}
\def\itemg{{\color{green}\item\leavevmode\ignorespaces}}
```

Both of the above doesn't use the optional argument associated with `\item` and therefore sets the label at that level.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\itemr{{\color{red}\item\leavevmode\ignorespaces}}
\def\itemg{{\color{green}\item\leavevmode\ignorespaces}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Hey!}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Now we test the colors
  \itemr This one should be in red
  \itemg This one green
  \itemg Only the bullets themselves are colored, which is the goal
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Now notice what happens when I color the nested list bullets too
    \item While the uncolored are dashes
    \itemr The colored ones are level 1 bullets again
    \itemr While I would like them to be colored dashes
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @OphirAverbuch: Your request now makes much more sense. I've updated my answer to accommodate for that.

Comment: That's it, Thanks!