# How do i change the format of the black dots in the itemize environment using enumitem?

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

I´m new to the "enumitem" package and would like to make an itemize with blue triangles, instead of the regular black dots. How do i do this? either as a global setting in my preamble or as a local setting for each itemize environment.

I want it to be like the picture, but just in a blue color.

[image: How do I do this?]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you only want a blue triangle or a blue triangle with a light gray shadow (as it seems to be the case in your screenhot)? Either way, you might be interested in [Change color of itemize bullet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318199/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,portrait,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}    
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}    
\newcommand{\myarrow}{    
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\fill[green](90:.1)--(0:.2)--(270:.1)--cycle;    
\end{tikzpicture}    
}
\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate}[\myarrow]    
\item This firts    
\item This second    
\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How is `\fillgreen` defined?

Comment: Your `\myarrow` macro contains two new paragraphs (actually four, but those inside the `tikzpicture` do no harm), I don't think that is intentional. You should change it's definition to not contain additional spaces or paragraphs by commenting out the line ending after the opening brace and the line ending after `\end{tikzpicture}`. Additionally you should remove the empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

A version without Ti*k*Z, but with `enumitem`, `amssymb` and `xcolor`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*\myarrow
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \rlap{\kern.1em\textcolor{gray}{$\blacktriangleright$}}%
    \raise.1em\hbox{\textcolor{orange}{$\blacktriangleright$}}%
    \kern.1em
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\myarrow]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `tikz` picture  can be set as label for `enumerate`

```
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\tikz{\fill[gray] (0,-0.05)--+(-0.1,-0.1)--+(-0.1,0.1)--cycle;\fill[orange] (0,0)--(-0.1,-0.1)--(-0.1,0.1)--cycle;}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\tikz{\fill[gray] (0,-0.05)--+(-0.1,-0.1)--+(-0.1,0.1)--cycle;\fill[orange] (0,0)--(-0.1,-0.1)--(-0.1,0.1)--cycle;}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item second
\item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```